# How to add a value to a counter, if the value in a cell equals a certain value?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, countif

I am looking for some help to find the average of the corresponding number for Whites and Blacks using a formula.
So if the Colour is White, how do I sum up all the numbers for White and find that Average. I understand that I would use the COUNTIF function if the Colour is White or Black but how would I add the value that corresponds to if the coloru is White or Black and then average the amount.

[image: Excel]

Comment: Are you looking for `AVERAGEIFS`?

Comment: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/averageifs-function-48910c45-1fc0-4389-a028-f7c5c3001690

Answer (score 0):

There are Simple Solutions

```
=AVERAGEIF(COLOR-NAME RANGE,"white",VALUE RANGE)
```

OR

```
=SUMIF(COLOR-NAME RANGE,"white",VALUE RANGE)/COUNTIF(COLOR-NAME RANGE,"white")
```